# Prepend hashtags in wordpress wp_tag_cloud

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

How can I prepend a "#" to the wp_tag_cloud?

This is my code so far

```
$args = array(
      'order'   => 'count',
      ); 
wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

A seperator does not work since this will not affect the first tag.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you opposed to adding them via CSS "content"?

Comment: hm how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of options here. Based on your code, it looks like you're using the default `'format'  => 'flat'` argument. If you want to use this, you *should* be able to prepend hashtags to each tag using CSS. Something like the following:

```
a[class^="tag-link-"]::before {
    content: '#';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `'format' => 'array'` argument to return an array of tags, and then loop through them and echo them however you want. In PHP, this would look something like:

```
$args = array(
    'order'   => 'count',
    'format'  => 'array',
); 
$tags = wp_tag_cloud( $args );

foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '#' . $tag . ' ';
}
```

Of course, there are even more elegant ways to use PHP to actually wrap the `#` in the same link tag.

Comment: Well, thank you! I am just too inexperienced to see things like that :) perfect solutions

Comment: You're welcome. Cool thing is, now that you've seen it, you'll likely add these techniques to your arsenal and start thinking about similar problems a bit differently.

Comment: Yes :) If i look a half year back, I have learned so much.. so your answer will bring me a step further as well.. But seriously, I don't know what I would do without stackoverflow :D Have a nice day!